# MAX and MIN value of RDD[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

in the following code I calculate the euclidean distance for each document to the cluster centroid in a KMeans cluster.
I feel like the euclidean distance does not make much sense so I thought normalizing it to a scale from from 0 to 1 would be better.

Unfortunately, I didn't figure out how to sort the `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]]` data type or how to get the maximum / minimum value.

In fact it is a `RDD[Map[String,Double]]` but I suppose it got converted to an `RDD[Map[String,Any]]` for some reason. Most approaches e.g `takeOrdered` results in:

> error: No implicit Ordering defined for scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]

How can I teach Scala how to sort the Any values of this Map?
Any hints are very much appreciated.

Thanks

```
val score = rdd.map({case(id,vector) => {distToCentroid(id, vector, model_1)}})

// Normalizing the data with normalizeResult function.
// Problem I need to find the max and minimum beforehand        
def distToCentroid(id: String, datum: Vector, model: KMeansModel) = {
  val cluster = model.predict(datum)
  val centroid = model.clusterCenters(cluster)
  val distance = math.sqrt(centroid.toArray.zip(datum.toArray).map(p => p._1 - p._2).map(d => d * d).sum)
  Map("id" -> id, "distance" -> distance)
}

def normalizeResult(max: Double, min: Double, x: Double) = { 
  (x-min) / (max-min)
}
```

Comment: Your map is of type `Map[String,Any]` because the key `"id"` maps to a `String` and `"distance"` maps to `Double`, and `Any` is the common base class for those.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Obviously both values "id" and "distance" have similar data types (String and Double) so there has to be a common class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right, you need global min/max for values, stored inside of maps. If so, you can just flatten your RDD and map it to RDD[Double]:

```
val values = rdd.flatMap(_.values.map(_.toDouble)).cache()
val min = values.min()
val max = values.max()
```

Comment: Your code works nicely and solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to Map the outputs directly in to the correct formats in the first instance.

`def distToCentroid(id: String, datum: Vector, model: KMeansModel) = {
val cluster = model.predict(datum)
val centroid = model.clusterCenters(cluster)
val distance = math.sqrt(centroid.toArray.zip(datum.toArray).map(p => p._1 - p._2).map(d => d * d).sum)
//Updated Outputs
Map("id" -> id, "distance" -> distance.toDouble)
}`

That should then allow you to either use the inbuilt min and max functions or use the function you have written.

---